# Jquery to store value on MouseOver on 2 different icons

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 different icons on a row having same class. When Click on any of the icons, the jquery event fired, BUT I need to store different values on MouseOver of respective icon.

**Jquery Code**

```
$('a.policyBreach').bind('click mouseover', function (e) {
if (event.type === "mouseover") {

// Need to Store differnt values for icons for Thumbs UP, and Thumbs Down respectively. Also, there is link to reference image. 

} else if (event.type === "click") {
blockStatus=1;
$(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', !0);
$('.overLayDiv').addClass('active');
$('.disableBlock').addClass('no-active');
$("#duplicateExpense").css('display','none');
$('#policyViolation').css('display','block');
$('#policyViolation').css('width','100%');
$('#policyViolation #btnRejectPayment-PV').css('display','none');
$('#policyViolation #closeRightSlider').css('display','block');
$('.rightSliderBg2').css('width','50%').addClass('active');
}
});
```

**[HTML Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW1gA.jpg)**

```
<td class="rowIcons text-right"><a class="dark-grey mouseOverTooltip"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a><a href="expense-approver-no-policy-breach.html" class="dark-grey "><i class="fas fa-file-signature"></i></a> <a class="thumbs-up policyBreach" ><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></a> <a class="thumbs-down policyBreach"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></a></td>
```

Reference Image:

[image: Reference Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a.policyBreach').bind('click mouseover', function (e) {
if (event.type === "mouseover") {
if($(this).hasClass("thumbs-up")) {
  // handle the value for thumbs-up
} else {
  // handle the value for thumbs-up
}
// Need to Store differnt values for icons for Thumbs UP, and Thumbs Down respectively. 

} else if (event.type === "click") {
blockStatus=1;
$(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', !0);
$('.overLayDiv').addClass('active');
$('.disableBlock').addClass('no-active');
$("#duplicateExpense").css('display','none');
$('#policyViolation').css('display','block');
$('#policyViolation').css('width','100%');
$('#policyViolation #btnRejectPayment-PV').css('display','none');
$('#policyViolation #closeRightSlider').css('display','block');
$('.rightSliderBg2').css('width','50%').addClass('active');
}
});
```